# Как расширить расширение системы рейтинга wp-recall добавив просмотры и баллы за лайки на счета двоих пользователей?

Tags: wordpress

нужно чтобы баллы шли за лайки на счета лайкнувшего и разместившего пост или комментарий
только не знаю как реализовать это в полной мере?

```
if(!is_admin()) add_action('init','rcl_register_add_view_type',30); 
if(is_admin()) add_action('admin_init','rcl_register_add_view_type',30); 
function rcl_register_add_view_type(){ rcl_register_rating_type(array('rating_type'=>'add-view','type_name'=>'просмотры','icon'=>'fa-plus')); }

add_action('','add_rating_with_add_view',10,2); 
function add_rating_with_add_view($comment_id,$comment){ global $rcl_rating_types; 
if(!$comment->user_id) return false; 
$args = array( 'user_id' => $comment->user_id, 'object_author' => $post->user_id, 'rating_value' => $rcl_rating_types['add-view']['type_point'], 'rating_type' => 'add-view' );
 rcl_insert_rating($args); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В плагине и так ставится лайк автору записи.
Просмотров ни в плагине, ни в вордпресс нет - это сторонний функционал и таких плагинов многое кол-во. Так что ответа конкретного тут быть не может.

Как работать с апи системы рейтинга и примеры - вам ссылка была дана ранее. Повторю её тут https://codeseller.ru/dokumentaciya-wp-recall/ документация - Пункты: "Подключаем к системе рейтинга WP-Recall произвольный объект" и
"Добавляем свой тип рейтинга в систему рейтинга WP-Recall"

Comment: как добавлять новый объект я прочитал ,но откуда взять учет просмотров вот в этом проблема  плагин просмотров WP-PostViews

Comment: а тому кто лайкнул не добавляется лайк .если он активен на форуме и пролайкал 1000 записей

Comment: Апи WP-Recall вам дали. Осталось понять про postviews и соединить.
Тот кто лайкнул - ему с какого перепуга что-то перепасть должно? Ниодна соцсеть себя так не ведет. Я написал комментарий - меня лайкнули. И на этом всё.

Comment: этот хук добавляет wiew к нему цеплять надо вашу функцию do_action( 'postviews_increment_views', $post_views + 1 );

Comment: только прицепится add_action( ( 'postviews_increment_views',